# Delimiter not increasing for vertical bar

Tags: delimiters

We are using XITS-Bold font for math, in the case of vertical bar the size has not increased. But in the case square and round bracket it works fine. Please suggest how to solve this. Is it possible to change delimiters into different font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{unicode-math}%
\setmathfont{xits-mathbold.otf}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


$\bigg \vert \begin{array}{lll}
\textbf{2} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{3}\\
\textbf{1} & - \textbf{1} & \textbf{2}\\
- \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{0}\end{array}\bigg \vert $

$\left \{ \begin{array}{lll}
\textbf{2} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{3}\\
\textbf{1} & - \textbf{1} & \textbf{2}\\
- \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{0}\end{array}\right \} $


$\left [ \begin{array}{lll}
\textbf{2} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{3}\\
\textbf{1} & - \textbf{1} & \textbf{2}\\
- \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{0}\end{array}\right ] $

$$
DE:AB = 18:6 \quad AB:12 = CE:15
$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using a fixed size and wonder that it does not grow?

Comment: Why `xits-mathbold`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're loading a boldface font as main math font; anyway, XITS BoldMath has several defects, among which that of not making `\vert` grow.

Your code shows other problems, though.

1. Load neither `xltxtra` nor `xunicode`.
2. Load `amsmath` earlier.
3. `Ligatures=TeX` is on by default.
4. `\textbf` should be `\symbf` (or `\mathbf` when `unicode-math` is not used).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}


$\left\vert \begin{array}{lll}
\symbf{2} & \symbf{1} & \symbf{3}\\
\symbf{1} & - \symbf{1} & \symbf{2}\\
- \symbf{1} & \symbf{2} & \symbf{0}
\end{array}\right \vert $

$\left \{ \begin{array}{lll}
\symbf{2} & \symbf{1} & \symbf{3}\\
\symbf{1} & - \symbf{1} & \symbf{2}\\
- \symbf{1} & \symbf{2} & \symbf{0}
\end{array}\right \} $


$\left [ \begin{array}{lll}
\symbf{2} & \symbf{1} & \symbf{3}\\
\symbf{1} & - \symbf{1} & \symbf{2}\\
- \symbf{1} & \symbf{2} & \symbf{0}
\end{array}\right ] $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits/issues/57

Answer (score 0):

The wrong sizing is due to the xits_mathbold.otf font, with xits_math.otf the vertical bars do resize. A workaround could be to switch to the xits-math font for that matrix.

In your code, even with the xits-math font, the vertical bars stay too small, but that's due to the use of \bigg\vert instead of \left\vert -- \right\vert. And why not use the (amsmath) matrix environments (vmatrix, Bmatrix, bmatrix)?

Comment: Hi Remco thanks for you suggestion, even vmatrix also not worked.